# ubuntu 16.04 auto load usb dvb-t dongle module

Tags: kernel, 16.04, dvb-t

The kernel module of a dvbt usb dongle is not loaded automatically when plugged in. dmesg prints on plugin of the dongle:

```
[25205.557608] usb 1-5: new high-speed USB device number 9 using ehci-pci
[25205.913622] usb 4-5: new full-speed USB device number 4 using ohci-pci
[25206.074971] usb 4-5: not running at top speed; connect to a high speed hub
[25206.089948] usb 4-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0bda, idProduct=2838
[25206.089960] usb 4-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[25206.089967] usb 4-5: Product: RTL2838UHIDIR
[25206.089973] usb 4-5: Manufacturer: Realtek
```

but the module is not loaded. It can be loaded by hand by typing:

```
sudo modprobe dvb-usb-rtl28xxu
```

after that, using it by e.g. Kaffeine works.

is there a way to have the module loaded automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can load the module automatically in this in two way:

**First Way:**
Edit `/etc/modules` file and add the name of the module to load at boot. To do so open the file with superuser permission:

```
sudo nano /etc/modules
```

and append a new line containing `dvb-usb-rtl28xxu`. To save and close the file press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then type `y`.

You can read more details [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules).

**Second Way:**
Add that command to `/etc/rc.local`. This script is executed every time that the PC is booted up.

To edit `rc.local` open it with superuser permission using this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/rc.local
```

Now you should see some comments and a `exit` function. You have to put your command after the comments, but before the `exit` function. The content of your file will look like this:

```
# some comments

modprobe dvb-usb-rtl28xxu

exit 0
```

After this, close the editor saving the `rc.local` file: press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and then type `y`.

---

In both cases, next time you boot your PC the module it should be loaded automatically.

I hope this could help you.

Comment: Putting the line into /etc/modules and during runtime plugging the device doesn't work. Is there a way to automatically load the module (systemd?)?

Comment: Have you also tried second way?

Comment: Thank you, second way (putting the line _modprobe dvb-usb-rtl28xxu_ into _/etc/rc.local_) works